# SpannableString highlights only the last character

Tags: java, android

I have a `TextView` that needs to be highlighted in multiple positions.
I've done this before with `EditText` and it worked fine.
The only difference is that `EditText` implements `Spannable` whereas `TextView` doesn't.
`TextView` seems to remain span only from the last `setSpan()` method call.

**Code**

```
TextView tvMainActivityTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvMainActivityTitle);
SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString(tvMainActivityTitle.getText());
ForegroundColorSpan color = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(192,0,0));
spanStr.setSpan(color, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanStr.setSpan(color, 2, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanStr.setSpan(color, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // <- this one wins
tvMainActivityTitle.setText(spanStr);
```

So it paints only the first character in the TextView.
I assume that TextView struggles with this type of task.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need multiple instances of `ForegroundColorSpan` for each set method & it will work.

For your example:

```
TextView tvMainActivityTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvMainActivityTitle);
SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString(tvMainActivityTitle.getText());
ForegroundColorSpan color1 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(192, 0, 0));
ForegroundColorSpan color2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(192, 0, 0));
ForegroundColorSpan color3 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(192, 0, 0));
spanStr.setSpan(color1, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanStr.setSpan(color2, 2, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanStr.setSpan(color3, 5, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // <- this one wins
tvMainActivityTitle.setText(spanStr);
```

Also for further read: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-styling-with-spans-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Refer [@Mayur Gajra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851329/9636037) for the solution.

Adding the reason why this happens for better understanding.

So, we can see that each span can only be used to set one span.
Why is that so?

On digging up the `SpannableString` `setSpan()`, I can see this code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (spans[i] == what) {
        int ostart = data[i * COLUMNS + START];
        int oend = data[i * COLUMNS + END];

        data[i * COLUMNS + START] = start;
        data[i * COLUMNS + END] = end;
        data[i * COLUMNS + FLAGS] = flags;

        sendSpanChanged(what, ostart, oend, nstart, nend);
        return;
    }
}
```

`what` is the span argument passed to the `setSpan` method. `what` is an object.
Hence `if (spans[i] == what)` checks if there is already a span set with the same instance. If so, the span is replaced with the new span.